# show the hierarchy of tree by showing path to leaf node

Tags: oracle

I want to write a query in oracle so that I can get my tree hierarchy in one row and only last node path is shown like I have a id and its parent id.

```
id                parent_id
1                 null
2                 1
3                 2
4                 3
5                 4
6                 5
```

and the output should be in one row like
path

```
1-2-3-4-5-6
```

Comment: could you post some sample data and also what you have tried so far, thanks

Comment: I have used this query
SELECT id, parent_id, LEVEL, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(id, '/') "Path" FROM hiErarchy2 
start with id=1 connect by prior id=parent_id;
but it is giving the whole path like -1-1-2-1-2-3-1-2-3-4-1-2-3-4-5 like this

Comment: can it be done by cte (common table expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use function `sys_connect_by_path()` and pseudocolumn `connect_by_is_leaf`:

```
select id, ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(id, '-'), '-') path
  from test where connect_by_isleaf = 1
  connect by prior id = parent_id
  start with parent_id is null
```

Output and [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c41c2/1):

```
ID   PATH
---  ---------------
  6  1-2-3-4-5-6
```

---

**Edit:** `where` clause is natural here, but for some reason you absolutely don't want it. You could use:

```
select id, path from (
  select id, ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(id, '-'), '-') path, connect_by_isleaf leaf
    from test connect by prior id = parent_id
    start with parent_id is null)
  connect by 1=0 start with leaf = 1
```

Comment: I dont want use the where clause and now here is another thing
et say I have two tree like
id                parent_id
1                 null
2                 1
3                 2
4                 3
5                 4
6                 5
7                 6
8                 3
9                 8
10               9
11               10
and the output now should be like
Path
1-2-3-4-5-6-7
1-2-3-8-9-10-11
how can I Show this?

Comment: It's exactly how my query works - you can see it in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87c50/1). `where connect_by_isleaf = 1` means: show only _leaf rows_ - so in this case these will be paths for id 7 and 11.

Comment: Yes, simple move inner query to `with ...` clause, like here: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87c50/2), second query uses CTE.

Comment: but the query is using connect by prior...how can it be ansi standard or how it is properly using cte as it is using connect by

Comment: I am using not exist in spite of minus but it is not working...any alternative for minus??

Comment: Simply change last line to: `where not exists (select parent_id from test where parent_id = t.id)` or alternatively to: `where id not in (select nvl(parent_id, 0) from test)` - both works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  LISTAGG(id, '-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) from trea_sort connect by PRIOR  id = parent start with parent is null
```

Comment: let say I have two tree like
id                parent_id
1                 null
2                 1
3                 2
4                 3
5                 4
6                 5
7                 6
8                 3
9                 8
10               9
11               10
and the output now should be like
Path
1-2-3-4-5-6-7
1-2-3-8-9-10-11
how can I Show this?